# Java 8 replacing operation in a stream

Tags: java-8

I have a list of Users . Now i want to replace a User satisfying the condition if user.getAge() is equal to 25 then a method will change that user object properties and add it to the existing list replacing the old User.  How we can do this in Java 8. I have come this much

```
List<User> usersWithModifiedUsers = users.stream().filter(e-> e.getAge()>25).map(e-> modify(e))
```

But confused with the rest,  can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

If you just want the list of modified users, then filter and map.

```
List<User> usersModified = users
    .stream()
    .filter(e-e.getAge() > 25)
    .map(e->modify(e))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want all the users with the altered and unaltered, then do a map.

```
users = users
    .stream()
    .map(e-> e.getAge() > 25 ? modify(e) : e )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that in the first case, you should be able to pass a method reference for `modify`

Comment: I was looking for this , thanks , the second method.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just replace the filtered item with all

```
usersModified.forEach(e-> (e.getAge()>25) ? modify(e) : e);
```

You can first filter the list then modify if you want list of the modified item

```
List<User> usersModified = users.stream().filter(e-> e.getAge()>25).collect(Collectors.toList());
usersModified.forEach(e-> modify(e));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<User> usersModified = users.stream()
    .map(e -> {
        if (e.getAge()==5) {
           //your logic here
        } else {
            return e;
        }
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This works.  But i am interested in the ternary operator than the if else so selecting @WJS answer

Comment: You never used any word like `ternary` in your question. If you want to modify your object, when getAge()==5, then you need to use code block, and you can't use ternary operator; however, if you just wish to create a new instance (which is not the case according to your question), then you can use something like `e.getAge()==5 ? new User() : e`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
List<User> usersModified = users.stream()
      .filter(e -> e.getAge() > 25)
      .map(e-> modify(e))
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: The modify should return the modified user, so, you can have your list back